# How can I move an object diagonally on Windows Phone?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to pull a sprite from point A(vector2) to point B(vector2) in my Windows Phone XNA game. GestureType.HorizontalDrag moves it horizontally and GestureType.VerticalDrag moves it vertically, how can I move the sprite diagonally?

The player should be able to pull the sprite in every direction if he touches the sprite with his finger. The sprite can't be moved if the player's finger isn't on the sprite.

How can I do that? How can I move an object diagonally on Windows Phone?

Comment: diagonal=vertical+horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `GestureType.FreeDrag` that may do what you want ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx)).

Otherwise, it may be worth implementing your own touch behaviour using `TouchPanel.GetState()`

Comment: Thanx. It works.